# File not found error: Trying to import csv file into python. No such file or directory

Tags: python, file

So I'm getting the error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

My csv file is ratings.csv I know for sure that my file exists.

Here's my code:

```
import csv

ifile = open('ratings.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
```

Comment: Hint: you might want to add the [Tag:python] tag, so python people will see it.

Comment: Did you run your script under the same directory of your csv file?

Answer (score 0):

The working directory may be different. So though the file is there in the directory you are looking at, the script is not being executed there.  Can you try with the full pathname of the file instead of the just the file name?

```html
import csv

ifile =  open('/home/dir2/dir3/ratings.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
```